# updating child plist programittically shown in simulator but not in device

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

I am implementing setting bundle first time and I have done it by creating Root.plist and Child.plist in Settings.bundle and have some fields in these plist.
I need to update the fields (add or remove) of Child.plist according to web services and I have written code for that in appdelegate. Its working fine in simulator (all fields are updated accordingly) but its not working in device.
Can any one suggest me what could be the reason of it.

code to copy plist to document directory and update that (as per the asnwer)

```
NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSString *path = [bundle stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Category.plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *dictOfPlist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *dictArray = [dictOfPlist valueForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Child.plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path1])
{
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath: path1 error:&error];
}
for (some condition) 
{
    // creating dictionary
    // add dictionary to array dictArray
}
[dictOfPlist setObject:dictArray forKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];
[dictOfPlist writeToFile:path1 atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem to write your PLIST. You need to copy your PLIST from your resources bundle into the documents directory and modify the PLIST inside this folder.

For that you can use this piece of code :

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”data” ofType:@”plist”];
     [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
}
```

Have a look [here](http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/).

Comment: yes, I tried it but its not working because I am using plist for settings and if we create child plist in document directory, its not accessible from Root.plist. Please suggest me how can I update child plist from code.

Comment: I have updated the question with code I am using to copy Category.plist (settings.bundle) to Child.plist (document directory) and have given the reference of Child.plist in Root.plist but nothing is displayed in child pane now.
I looked into some more document and links and found that we can not update setting bundle programmitically. Please suggest me any other approach which I can use here
It seems that Root.plist is unable to access Child.plist.